# How do we get WS02 ESB Tokens if API is enabled

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2-esb

We are using WS02 ESB to create cloud app connections to our platform.

Our current issue: If we want to connect to any app (take salesforce as an example), we need the following details:

1. UserName
2. Password
3. Token
4. As a pre-requisite, the salesforce account should be API enabled.
   We thought of using SSO in backend to avoid (3) and (4), but it's not possible with SAML(SSO).We are looking into ways to connect and publish data to salesforce with just Username(1)/Password(2). In this process of evaluation, SSO is one of the options

Any suggestions on how we can get the below details for APPS would be much appreciated!

•   How do we get Token
•   How we accept only the accounts where API's are enabled.

Comment: so if i understand you questions, you want to create API in WSO2 ESB, this API request is required username/pwd. In ESB, you wan to call back end services and pass username/pwd. But these back end services required security check like SAML or AUTH. so you want to get these SAML or OAuth token in ESB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you need is to call an SAML SSO secured backend app (i.e :- salesforce)?. If its the case you may use WSO2 Identity server for this purpose.You can [obtain tokens](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/How+To%3A+Configure+the+Identity+Server+to+Issue+Security+Tokens) from it.Further You can use [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/WSO2+Identity+Server+and+Claim+Aware+Proxy+Services+with+ESB) guide and [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/) to call SAML secured backends through ESB.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ESB Connectors to connect with Salesforce API. You can find [Salesforce SOAP connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/fbb433b5-4d74-4064-84c2-e4b23c531aa2) (which uses the username, password, and security token for authentication), [Salesforce REST connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/43e44763-0d73-4ab3-8ae9-d6f73532d164) (which uses OAuth protocol) and [Salesforce bulk connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/3957b581-86e0-4909-ab75-c3cfa2ce6494) (which also uses OAuth protocol) at WSO2 Store.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 we have 150+ ESB connectors to communicate with third party API's via ESB. You can download the connector from [WSO2 Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/list) and can follow the documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/WSO2+ESB+Connectors+Documentation). In connectors we have the mechanism to connect the third party API's(For Example In salesforce SOAP based connector we had the username password flow and for Salesforce REST connector we had oAuth 2.0 flow and the username password flow). In all connectors you just call the init method to get the Token to access the API.